# Customize show_more tag in django-endless-pagination?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-endless-pagination

I use pagination on scroll by [Django EL(Endless) Pagination](http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library in my project.

By default `show_more` tag show `loading` word. I want customize it. I use next code but it work incorrect. It show me 9 icons and at the end don't disappear. I am little bit confused. How to fix it?

**settings.py:**

```
EL_PAGINATION_LOADING = """<i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw text-info text-justify endless_loading'>"""
```

**CURRENT SOLUTION:**

I found the working solution but I am not sure that its best and clear way to do that.

**custom_tags.py:**

```
from django import template
from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri
from el_pagination import (settings, utils)

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('documents/show_more_info.html', takes_context=True)
def show_more_info(context, label=None, loading=settings.LOADING, class_name=None):
    data = utils.get_data_from_context(context)
    page = data['page']
    if page.has_next():
        request = context['request']
        page_number = page.next_page_number()
        querystring_key = data['querystring_key']
        querystring = utils.get_querystring_for_page(
            request, page_number, querystring_key,
            default_number=data['default_number'])
        return {
            'label': label,
            'loading': loading,
            'class_name': class_name,
            'path': iri_to_uri(data['override_path'] or request.path),
            'querystring': querystring,
            'querystring_key': querystring_key,
            'request': request,
        }
    return {}
```

**documents/show_more_info.html:**

```
{% load i18n %}
{% if querystring %}
    <div class="endless_container">
        <a class="endless_more{% if class_name %} {{ class_name }}{% endif %}" href="{{ path }}{{ querystring }}" data-el-querystring-key="{{ querystring_key }}">
            {% if label %}{{ label|safe }}{% else %}{% trans "more" %}{% endif %}
        </a>
        <div class="endless_loading" style="display: none;">
            <div class="alert alert-info infinite-loading text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Finally I can use `show_more_info` tag instead of default `show_me` tag.

Comment: http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html  AND http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/javascript.html This didn't work for you?

Comment: Hello! I set only `EL_PAGINATION_LOADING` in `settings.py` file. It seems like it's not enough.

Comment: @AnupYadav I found the working solution, but I am not sure that its best and clear way to do that. I think its possible to make this task more easy. Do you have any ideas, my friend?!

Comment: I had used same module, but I also faced some other issues, then I had moved to jQuery's core solution. You get full control on your code.

Comment: You want to say that my solution is not so bad as I think?

Comment: If you full fill requirement then it's good, problem comes when more customization needed.

Comment: Ok. Can you show me your solution where you use only jquery if it possible?

Comment: http://voidcanvas.com/top-10-jquery-infinite-scrolling-plugin-with-demo/ Here you go, I had used for my previous company I don't remember library name. But you can try from above.

Comment: Thank you for this link, bro! :)